# Two USB drives as RAID 1 array?

Tags: usb, raid

Can two drives connected via USB be configured as a two-disk RAID 1 array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though the problem with USB is that if you suspend the system, they "unplug" so that will cause problems if you ever suspend.  You will need to manually unmount and then `mdadm --stop` the array before suspending or actually unplugging the drives.

Comment: Thanks. I don't plan on suspending the server. I'll give this a go and see what happens.